# How to get text from "<a href" and replace in "<p>"

Tags: jquery

i try to use jquery .text() but not really work :

Before

```
<a id="group_name" href="index.php">Felda</a>
<p id="here"></p>
```

After

```
<a id="group_name" href="index.php">Felda</a>
<p id="here">Felda</p>
```

Comment: what have you tried? and word of advise people are more likely to help ou if you show appreciation of that help (Ie accept answers)

Comment: Show us your use of `.text()`.

Comment: Post the code that `not really work`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#here').text($('#group_name').text());
```

The above code should work.

Comment: yes now it;s working,really appreciate. :)

Comment: @xdazz **working demo** for you: http://jsfiddle.net/AvxyU/ ;)) If anyone interested!

Comment: last question can i add something "<span>" before 'felda' like <a href=""><span>felda</span></a>

Comment: @ruslyrossi Yes, if you use the html content, you could use the .html() instead .text().

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the jQuery function [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
var a_text = $("#group_name").text();
$("#here").text(a_text);
```